# Mod_rewrite - deny access except specific pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have a rewrite rule that redirects anyone not in the office to a holding page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteRule . holdingpage.html

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]
```

I need allow google to access its google verification file:
https://www.example.com/google23423423463.html

Is there a way to add a rewrite to allow anyone not in the office to access this page, as well as be redirected to the holding page when accessing any other page?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If request is for special page, skip all rules below
RewriteRule ^google23423423463\.html$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteRule . holdingpage.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Spot on, does exactly what I needed.  Thanks.